# Schedule a job once every day on work days in jenkins

Tags: build, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins. I need to schedule the job in Jenkins to run at 3 PM every working day (MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI).

Is the below format correct?

```
00 15 * * 1-5
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this will execute the task as 15:00 each Monday to Friday. and the actual record should looks like:

```
0 15 * * 1-5 /path/to/command
```

Answer (score 1):

This command is correct.

If you want to test out different cron schedule expressions, have a look at:
https://crontab.guru/

You can enter your cron schedule expression and the website will give you a human readable version of the expression.